# AngularJS routing for beginner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to reproduce routing example in my AngularJS book PDF. Having trouble to make it work, I have copy/paste the code in the book to avoid syntax error... But I don't understand what's wrong.

When I load `http://127.0.0.1:8080/routes/` I should see the content of "index.html" and the content of list.html "inside".

But I only see a blamk page with "A-Mail" (the content of index.html)

I have set some breakpoints with chrome debug tools, it seems that I enter in "`when('/routes/')`" section of *routeProvider*, but never in *ListController* function...
I don't have errors in console log

**controllers.js**

```
    // Creates a module for our core AMail services
var aMailServices = angular.module('AMail', []);

// Set up our mappings between URLs, templates, and controllers
function emailRouteConfig($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/routes/', {
        controller: ListController,
        templateURL: 'list.html'
    }).
    // Notice that for the detail view, we specify a parameterized URL component
    // by placing a colon in front of the id
    when('/routes/view/:id', {
        controller: DetailController,
        templateURL: 'detail.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/routes/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}

// Set up our route so the AMail service can find it
aMailServices.config(emailRouteConfig)

// Some fake emails
messages = [{
        id: 0, sender: 'jean@somecompany.com', subject: 'Hi there, old friend',
        date: 'Dec 7, 2013 12:32:00', recipients: ['greg@somecompany.com'],
        message: 'Hey, we should get together for lunch sometime and catch up.'
        +'There are many things we should collaborate on this year.'
    }
];

// Publish our messages for the list template
function ListController($scope){
    $scope.messages = messages;
}

// Get the message id from the route (parsed from the URL) and use it to
// find the right message object
function DetailController($scope, $routeParams){
    $scope.message = messages[$routeParams.id];
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="AMail">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title...</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A-Mail</h1>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**detail.html**

```
<div><strong>Subject: </strong>{{message.subject}}</div>
<div><strong>Sender: </strong>{{message.sender}}</div>
<div><strong>Date: </strong>{{message.date}}</div>
<div>
    <strong>To:</strong>
    <span ng-repeat='recipient in message.recipients'>{{recipient}}</span>
    <div>{{message.message}}</div>
    <a href='#/'>Back to message list</a>
</div>
```

**list.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Sender</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Subject</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <td>{{message.sender}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/view/{{message.id}}">{{message.subject}}</a></td>
        <td>{{message.date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you

Comment: Does you server support `html5Mode` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [the offical document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider), I think that you should use `templateUrl` instead of `templateURL`.